Angular reactive form hasValidator return false for custom validator function
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function trimValidator(minlength: number, maxlength: number): ValidatorFn {
  return ({ value }: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const trimValue = value?.trim() || '';
    if (trimValue.length < minlength) {
      return { minlength: true }; 
    } else if (trimValue.length > maxlength) {
      return { minlength: true }; }
    };
}


// ====================================================================
myform = this.fbgroup({
  name: ['', [Validators.required]],
  description: ['', [trimValidator(10, 3000)]]
});

// When i access default validator through hasValidator then i got true but when
i pass custom validator functiion to hasvalidator then return me false
// inside custom-directive.ts
this.myform.get('name')?.hasValidator(Validator.required)  // true

this.myform.get('description')?.hasValidator(trimValidator(10, 3000))  // false


Have you tried to pass the validator function as this.myform.get('description')?.hasValidator(trimValidator)) instead of call it?

Hi @DmitryS. tried, its throwing error

From the hasValidator docs:

The provided validator must be a reference to the exact same function that was provided.

Create a variable used to store the reference:
trimValidator = trimValidator(10, 3000);

myform = this.fb.group({
   name: ['', [Validators.required]],
  description: ['', [this.trimValidator]],
});

Provide the variable to hasValidator:
this.myform.get('description')?.hasValidator(this.trimValidator)

Note that your current trimValidator has an error that returns undefined and it is not matched with the return type. You should add return null:
export function trimValidator(
  minlength: number,
  maxlength: number
): ValidatorFn {
  return ({ value }: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const trimValue = value?.trim() || '';
    if (trimValue.length < minlength) {
      return { minlength: true };
    } else if (trimValue.length > maxlength) {
      return { minlength: true };
    }

    return null;
  };
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

let me try this but one thing i forgot to metion that hasValidator check is in another file (inside custom directive), but i got your pont
